# How does running Xilinx synthesis tool on non-synthesizable VHDL code let the designer know the VHDL code is non-synthesizable?

Tags: vhdl

How does running Xilinx synthesis tool on non-synthesizable VHDL code let the designer know the VHDL code is non-synthesizable? Is the presence of warnings and errors thrown by Xilinx synthesis tool the criteria that lets the a designer know the VHDL code is not synthesizable?

Comment: Warnings and errors can be anything like missing a semicolon. So it has no direct relationship with synthesising. You have to check the synthesis report to know how tool tried to synthesise the code and was it successful.

Comment: Assuming synthesis completes without critical warnings, the best thing is to look at the schematic of the synthesized design and see if it built a circuit that accomplishes your goal.